# 'new' keyword not used in some situations

Tags: java, c#, selenium, object

I see that you initialize an object using the new Keyword.like in

```
WedDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
```

but in some situations it is not used. like in

```
DesiredCapabilities caps= DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
```

Why is it not used in the second situation above?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/79b3xss3.aspx

Comment: First learn the difference between a new object and a function.

Comment: I haven't touched Java in years so I don't have a definitive answer, but often that method of getting an instance of something is using 'new' internally.  The method is doing some checking to make sure that everything that needs to be there is in fact there, and won't return an instance if there is a problem.  This makes it impossible to construct an instance that is unusable for any reason.  That syntax can also be used with a Singleton design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you are telling java to construct the object (reserve storage) and call the constructor for the class to initialize the object.

In the second example your a calling a static method (Class method) and it under the covers is either doing the new for you or finding a reference to an already constructed object it can return.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Below is the code. Why did they use DesiredCapabilities as the reference type. Is this how it is done? You take the same class as the refrence type if you are storing the result of a method from the class?.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Below is the code. Why did they use DesiredCapabilities as the reference type. Is this how it is done? You take the same class as the refrence type if you are storing the result of a method from the class?. Also, I am new to programming. does the firefox() method here need to have a return type or or it just means that a combination of the variables and calculations inside the firefox() method will be stored in the reference variable (caps here) as a set? Just for reference, I have pasted the complete code in my question just so that it is easy to understand the context.

Comment: sorry, just realized I cant edit my original question

Comment: the firefox method will likely be defined with a return type of DesiredCapabilities or something that can be cast to that.  so within firefox()  you would see something like:

return new DesiredCapabilities(parm1,parm2);

that is one possibility of how the return will return a reference to the object to assign to the var caps in your code example.

Answer (score 0):

The `new` keyword is used to call a class' constructor.  It's the only way to create a new instance of a class.

So `WedDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();` is creating a new instance of the `FirefoxDriver` class (which, in this example, derives from the `WedDriver` class).

The second example you have, without the `new` keyword, is an example of a variable assignment from an existing object reference (i.e. one that was already instantiated at some point before) which is returned by a call to the `firefox()` method in the `DesiredCapabilities` class:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps= DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
```